# Adblock CSS Wildcard for Quora?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, ublock-origin

Quora has this annoying randomized CSS Wrapper attribute

[image]

What i want to do is basically block *_wrapper, but adblock filter syntax is complicated and all the examples i've seen when searching for a solution don't seem easily adaptable to my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this under "My filters".

```
! Quora Anti Ublock
www.quora.com##.condensed_ad_experiment.PromptsList
www.quora.com##DIV[class="upper_content_group"]
www.quora.com##DIV[class="upper_content linked_content question_page_content lower_slot linked_content"]
www.quora.com##DIV[class="ErrorBanner fade_in"]
```

Comment: It doesn't work the confirm button is greyed out

Comment: nvm i misread your instructions.